# Node JS expess session undefined when running on docker, but runs fine on MAC

Tags: session, express, docker, redis

I have a simple Node JS web application server that allows a user to login and post/edit a simple blog. I use **Redis** as my session store and **CouchDB** as my DB. I run everything (Node app, Redis, Couch DB) on my MAC & use my browser running on MAC to connect to it (https://localhost:3000 or localhost:3001). I can login, post/edit blogs everything works fine.

Last week i tried dockerizing my Node JS app. Basically, my node app runs on the docker container, however my redis and couchdb continue to run on the host (ie, my MAC). I have used docker-machine to dockerize the node app.

Docker machine(Docker VM) has the IP: **192.168.99.101**
My MAC IP: **192.168.0.100**

I connect my browser as (**https://192.168.99.101:3000** or **192.168.99.101:3001**) & i see the login page. I then enter the logging credentials. My browser POSTs the page to the node app on docker. The node app reads the user, passwd from CouchDB (running on the MAC host) and successfully verifies that the password is correct. However the node server is unable to get a valid session from the POST request object and therefore unable to save the session. I have gone through many stackoverflow and other articles online on this subject and none helped.

I have made sure network is NOT the issue. ie, I am able to access redis & couchdb from the docker shell using the curl command.

Is connecting my browser to a different physical IP causing the problem here ? Should i be switching to a domain name ? I would like to better understand what's going on here. Appreciate your help.

***Initialization:***

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const mustache = require('mustache');

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
//var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const redis   = require("redis");
const redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
const redisClient  = redis.createClient();
:
:
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
   session(
   {
    secret: REDIS_SECRET_KEY,
    // create new redis store.
    store: new redisStore({ host: REDIS_SERVER_HOST, port: REDIS_SERVER_PORT, client: redisClient,ttl :  260}),
    // REDIS_SERVER_HOST = 192.168.0.100, REDIS_SERVER_PORT=6379
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: { expires: false, maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }
   }));

 :
 :
 // Logic to setup various routes

 app.get('/', function(req, res)
 {
    var userName = getUserName(req);
    if (userName != "")
      res.redirect('/home');
    else
      res.redirect('/login');
  });

  /** Login page. After login user is redirected to home page */
 app.get('/somepage', function(req, res)
 {
   :
 });
 :
 :
```

***Login function is not seeing cookies or session when running on docker. It sees everything when run on my MAC.***

```
function login(user, passwd, dbPasswd)
{
    if (dbPasswd == passwd)
    {
       // Store userID in REDIS session!
       if (postReq.cookies)
         console.log("Cookie:  -> ", postReq.cookies); // Cookie is empty when on docker, but is fine when run on my MAC
       postReq.session.key = userName; // BOMBS on docker, works fine when run on my MAC
       postResp.redirect("/home");
    }
    // Logic to handle login failure
}
```

When run on docker i see the below error:

```
/usr/src/app/mysource.js:760
           postReq.session.key = userName;
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'key' of undefined
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/mysource.js:760:26)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

To the best of my ability I have verified the below:
1) The node app runs fine on my MAC
2) There is no network issue between the docker & MAC. I am able to access redis, couchDB from the docker shell
3) The package.json & the node modules are identical between MAC & docker environments
4) Read several articles on the subject, but could not tell what's going wrong

Please help!!

Comment: Try adding event listeners to the redis client to help you debug your connections. Here's an example I put together a while ago https://github.com/ruedamanuel/node-boilerplate/blob/master/app.js#L70.It should work with your setup.

Answer (score 4):

Atlast, i figured out the issue with my code. Many thanks to rudeamanuel for his very useful tip on adding event listener for redisClient.

When I added the event listener the docker deployment of my node app kept spitting connection errors with redis as below:

```
UNABLE to establish connection with Redis
{ [Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379 }
```

Recall that i had initialized my express session as below, so i was scratching my head on why it would keep connecting to localhost in spite of me specifying the correct redis host.

```
const redisClient  = redis.createClient();
:
:
app.use(
   session(
   {
    secret: REDIS_SECRET_KEY,
    // create new redis store.
    store: new redisStore({ host: REDIS_SERVER_HOST, port: REDIS_SERVER_PORT, client: redisClient,ttl :  260}),
    // REDIS_SERVER_HOST = 192.168.0.100, REDIS_SERVER_PORT=6379
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: { expires: false, maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }
   }));
```

It appears the below statement is the problem:

```
new redisStore({ host: REDIS_SERVER_HOST, port: REDIS_SERVER_PORT, client: redisClient,ttl :  260})
```

When i initialize redisClient, it appears the client defaults to localhost and 6379 and subsequently when I initialize the redisStore with both client and the host, port info, the redisStore object ignores the host/port and takes the client object's parameters. So to solve this i do the below:

```
redisClient  = redis.createClient(REDIS_SERVER_PORT, REDIS_SERVER_HOST);
:
:

 app.use(session(
       {
        secret: REDIS_SECRET_KEY,
        // create new redis store.
        store: new redisStore({client: redisClient, ttl:  260}),
        saveUninitialized: false,
        resave: false,
        cookie: { expires: false, maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }
       }));
```

This fixes it. Many, many thanks to this forum I was able to resolve my issue quickly. You guys are awesome!